# Apostrophe looking for `apostrophe-pieces-pages` template in `apostrophe-pages`

Tags: apostrophe-cms

So `profile-components-pages` extends `apostrophe-pieces-pages` without any problems, but whenever I try and visit a page with the type `key-resources-pages` I get the following error:

```
Error: template not found: pages/key-resources-pages.html
```

This leads me to believe it's looking for the template in `apostrophe-pages` as opposed to `key-resources-pages`, which doesn't make the most sense to me considering I've added it to `app.js` and `apostrophe-pages`. Here's snippets of everything relevant:

***App.js:***

```
'apostrophe-link-widgets': {},
'home-card-widgets': {},
'learning-offerings': {},
'profile-components': {},
'profile-components-pages': {},
'key-resources': {},
'key-resources-pages': {},
's2sl-widgets': {},
'static-assets': {}
```

***lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.html:***

```
module.exports = {
  types: [
    {
      name: 'home',
      label: 'Home'
    },
    {
      name: 'profile-components-pages',
      label: 'GBS Success Profile'
    },
    {
      name: 's2sl',
      label: 'Space to Succeed Live'
    },
    {
      name: 'key-resources-pages',
      label: 'Resource Page'
    }
  ]
}
```

***lib/modules/key-resources/index.html:***

```
module.exports = {        
  name: 'key-resource',        
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',        
  label: 'Key Resource',        
  pluralLabel: 'Key Resources',
  ...
}
```

***lib/modules/key-resources-pages/index.htmi:***

```
module.exports = {          
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',          
  label: 'Resource Page',          
  addFields: [...]          
};
```

All the modules were initially created with the apostrophe-cli, and modified as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick modification fixed the problem. I was missing a `name` field for the `key-resources-pages` module, and I renamed it to be singular. My modifications (not including the rest of the content of the files) are as follows:

***lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.html***

```
module.exports = {
  types: [
    {
      name: 'key-resource-page',
      label: 'Resource Page'
    }
  ]
}
```

***lib/modules/key-resources-pages/index.html:***

```
module.exports = {          
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
  name: 'key-resource-page',
  label: 'Resource Page',          
  addFields: []          
};
```